# Can I make JavaScript use a fixed array over a dynamic array when making a Pascal's triangle generator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, math

More specifically, am I actually using arrays here.  I never declared the size of the array, I just start adding numbers to the chosen index.

To me, this is suspicious, and makes me think that JavaScript might be using a hash map instead of an array, which would involve more computation.

Can I make JavaScript use a fixed array over a dynamic array over a hash?

Is there a way to verify the underlying data structure without digging through the code base?

```
var generate = function(n) {
  const matrix = [[1], [1, 1]];

  // base case : n = 1
  if(n === 1) {
    return [[1]];
  }

  // base case : n = 2
  if(n === 2) {
    return matrix;
  }

  // first iterative case : n = 3
  // be careful of off by one error here
  // n is number of rows (3), but i is 0 based (2)
  for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {

    // add empty row
    matrix[i] = [];

    for(let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      // if first or last element set to 1
      if( j === 0 || j === i ) {
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
      } else {
        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1] + matrix[i-1][j]
      }
    }
  }
  return matrix;

};
```

Comment: decent read: [\[V8 Deep Dives\] Understanding Array Internals](https://itnext.io/v8-deep-dives-understanding-array-internals-5b17d7a28ecc)

Answer (score 2):

> makes me think that JavaScript might be using a hash map instead of an array, which would involve more computation.

Without looking at the actual code, this is true. In JavaScript an array is just a plain object (i.e. dictionary) with additional features. The indexes are properties that happen to represent non-negative integer (in a certain range). Although the engine *might* store the array as a *consecutive* array (as you would expect in C-style languages), the engine is free to really use a hash table like it would for any other object. It may even decide at run time to switch from one internal representation to another (transparent to the code).

> Can I make JavaScript use a fixed array over a dynamic array over a hash?

Yes, there are [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray), like [Int16Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int16Array)

Comment: `Array` is a really misleading name for what it does in JavaScript sadly